# Alternar o texto de um elemento a cada clique

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-eventos

Estou querendo ficar mudando o que está escrito no DOM como um *loop*. Mas quando ele vai para o final do `teste1` e chama o `teste`, não deveria começar de novo a função `teste`?

```
document.addEventListener("click", principal)

function principal() {

    document.addEventListener("click", teste)

    function teste() {
        document.querySelector('div#mod').innerText = 'Claro'
        document.addEventListener("click", teste1)
    }

    function teste1() {
        document.querySelector('div#mod').innerText = 'Escuro'
        document.addEventListener("click", teste)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você só quer ficar mudando o texto a cada vez que ocorre um clique, não precisa de um *loop*, e muito menos de registrar várias vezes as mesmas funções. Basta registrar apenas uma vez, uma única função que verifique o texto atual e mude-o para o outro valor:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let elemento = document.querySelector('div#mod');
    if (elemento.innerText === 'Claro') {
        elemento.innerText = 'Escuro';
    } else {
        elemento.innerText = 'Claro';
    }
});
```

```html
Clique para mudar o texto<br>
<div id="mod">
</div>
```

Repare que assim você não precisa ficar registrando funções a todo momento. Basta registrar o *listener* uma vez, que a função se encarrega de verificar o texto atual e mudá-lo.

---

Se quiser ter várias opções de texto e ir alternando entre elas, uma alternativa é criar um array com os textos possíveis e ir iterando por eles:

```js
var opcoes = ['Claro', 'Escuro', 'Branco', 'Cinza'];
var counter = 0;
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('div#mod').innerText = opcoes[counter];
    counter = (counter + 1) % opcoes.length;
});
```

```html
Clique para mudar o texto<br>
<div id="mod">
</div>
```

O operador `%` (resto da divisão) garante que eu volto para o início do array quando o contador ultrapassar o tamanho do mesmo.

---

#### Porque o seu código não funcionou

Da forma que você fez, estava registrando um *listener* novo a cada clique, pois `addEventListener` [tem efeito acumulativo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876794): cada vez que você a chama, está registrando um novo *listener*, que será executado junto com os outros que já estavam registrados. Isso faz com que as funções sejam executadas várias vezes.

Veja o exemplo abaixo (é basicamente o seu código com algumas modificações para entendermos melhor o que está acontecendo):

```js
var i = 0;
document.addEventListener("click", principal);

function principal() {
    console.log(i++, 'principal');
    document.addEventListener("click", teste);

    function teste() {
        console.log(i++, 'Claro');
        document.addEventListener("click", teste1);
    }

    function teste1() {
        console.log(i++, 'Escuro');
        document.addEventListener("click", teste);
    }
}
```

```html
Clique para disparar as chamadas das funções<br>
<div id="mod">
</div>
```

Primeiro registramos a função `principal` no evento de clique.

E na primeira vez que você clica, ele executa a função `principal`, que não chama as outras funções (ela só **registra** o evento de clique para chamar a função `teste`, mas `teste` ainda não é chamada aqui) e imprime `"0 principal"`.

Depois, quando você clica novamente, ele executa a função `principal` (que imprime `"1 principal"` e registra **outro** evento de clique para chamar `teste` - ou seja, agora temos 2 chamadas a `teste` registradas). Depois é executada a função `teste` (que foi registrada quando clicamos a primeira vez), que imprime `"2 Claro"` e registra o evento de clique para chamar `teste1`.

Na próxima vez que clicar, ele executa `principal`, `teste` duas vezes (pois registramos o respectivo evento duas vezes) e `teste1` (imprimindo `"3 principal"`, `"4 Claro"`, `"5 Claro"` e `"6 Escuro"`). Lembrando que a chamada a `principal` registra outro evento para chamar `teste`, e cada chamada de `teste` registra outro evento para chamar `teste1`.

E `teste1`, por sua vez, registra **outro** evento de clique para chamar `teste` (que registrará outro evento para chamar `teste1` a cada vez que for chamada e assim por diante). Depois de alguns cliques, ficará impossível controlar e entender o que está acontecendo.

Por isso a melhor solução é registrar o evento apenas uma vez.

Answer (score 2):

Uma coisa é registar um auscultador de evento `document.addEventListener`; outra coisa é ativá-lo. Para ativar um auscultador de evento é preciso clicar na página (nesse caso do evento `click`) ou disparar um evento sintético.

Para disparar um evento sintético podes fazer assim:

```js
var event = new Event('click');

// Listen for the event.
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Clique!!', e.isTrusted);
}, false);

// Dispatch the event.
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
Clica aqui também...
```

Repara que o sintético tem a propriedade `isTrusted` como `false`, mas funciona para um certo tipo de funcionalidade.

Atenção:

- encadear funções que se chamam mutuamente pode gerar um loop infinito e fazer o browser parar.
- cada vez que corres essas funções estás a adicionar novos auscultadores de eventos. Todos serão chamados quando houver um `clique` na página, e que por sua vez irá adicionar ainda mais auscultadores...